# How do I translate a word received from the Api into another language?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I get the name of the city from the api, but unfortunately there is no type translation function in the api (lang=en). I get the name of the city written in English, but written translated into my language, but I want the correct language to be used

```
MY_API:
data class WeatherLocation(
    val country: String,
    val lat: Double,
    @SerializedName("localtime_epoch")
    val localtimeEpoch: Long,
    val lon: Double,
    val name: String,
    val region: String,
    @SerializedName("tz_id")
    val tzId: String

)




    private fun updateCondition(condition: String) {
                textView_condition.text = condition
            }
```

Comment: This is not Android related. Try finding more info on the documentation of the api you're using

Comment: I write that there is no such function in the api

Comment: APIs very very rarely handle that, because that isn't their job.  They aren't a translation service (unless that's literally all they do).  Any translation would be 100 percent on you to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to make requests in java with a lot of API-s on internet about this, Just search.